# How do I manipulate a large number of images' pixel values effectively?

Tags: image, programming-languages, wolfram-mathematica, average, addition

After reading [an article about Fingerprinting in digital cameras](http://33bits.org/2011/09/19/digital-camera-fingerprinting/), I would like to do some research of my own to see if my camera is having some kind of fingerprints. The first idea I want to try is to take average of some hundreds to thousands of picture taken from my camera and make a picture whose pixel value is the average of each corresponding pixel from every image. If there is some kind of distortion, e.g a pixel that feels the light 1/256 stronger than it should feel, it can be revealed.

What is an efficient way to manipulate this large amount of data? I would welcome all kinds of softwares and languages.

I used to use ImageData[image] function in Mathematica to transform an image to an array of pixel values and then add and average the ImageData[images] all together, then use Image[data] function to transform the array back to image, but the process seems to be too slow.

Comment: `ImageAdd` might be faster, but I'd guess pretty much any compiled language will blow away mathematica.  I really dont think this will work however, you need to do what they say in the article and look at some highly uniform images.

Comment: I'd test @george's guess that a compiled language will blow away Mathematica.  I naively expect Mathematica to be using routines written in C (or C++ or some other compiled language) to implement the sort of functionality you want, and if you steer clear of symbolic operations Mathematica's speed is often fast enough.  Given that it will take you what, say an hour at least, to find and figure out a C++ (or your favourite language) library, Mathematica will probably have ripped through a few thousand images before you have started using the faster code.

Comment: blow away might be a tad strong, and you are right for a one-off project i would use mathematica every time. A little performance gain isn't worth hours/days writing c code.

Answer (score 0):

Since I mentioned it in comment, it turns out `ImageAdd` is not much different than summing the imagedata:

```
 images =  
     Select[ExampleData /@ ExampleData["TestImage"] ,
       ImageDimensions[#] == {512, 512} && 
       ImageColorSpace[#] == "RGB" & ] ;   
 images = Flatten@Table[ images, {10} ];
 n = Length[images];
 (sum = ImageMultiply[ images[[1]] , 1/n ];
 (sum = ImageAdd[sum, ImageMultiply[ #, 1/n ]]) & /@ images[[2;;]];)
     // AbsoluteTiming (* {0.842362, Null} *)
 sum2 = (Total@(ImageData /@ images ))/n; 
     // AbsoluteTiming (* {0.873561, Null} *)
```

Note that either way we are summing 80 images in ~ 1 second.  My guess is your real bottleneck lies in the `Import` operation (which is where I think "C" would win out )

In this case I would stick with summing the `ImageData`. `ImageData` does some sort of clipping/normalizing which isn't well documented (hence the `ImageMultiply` trick - which cost you a bit of time but not near as much as the add )

### reading files

try this for loading and summing a bunch of files:

```
 filenames = FileNames["*.jpg",fullpath];
 sum = Total@(ImageData[Import[#]] & /@ filenames)/Length[filenames];
 Image[sum]
```

Note this will break if the files are not all the same size and color type.

Comment: I did not do extensive studies on Mathematica programming, and I might have tried an inefficient way to do this: Image[(ImageData[//drag my first image, which is an 1.8 MB 3648*2736 jpg from explorer into Mathematica and it takes about 5 seconds]+ImageData[second image]+ImageData[third image]+ImageData[fourth image]+ImageData[fifth image])/5]. For five pictures it takes about 10 seconds to calculate an average of five.